# Convert PDF to JPGs - two-page spreads?

Tags: imagemagick

I've written a script to use ImageMagick to convert PDFs into JPGs for each page, along with resizing/etc.

Where it gets slightly more tricky is some PDFs have the middle two-page spread as "one page" - so it is extra wide. Is there ANY way to "detect" this and crop the left and right sides, as two separate pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to use ImageMagick (and *only* ImageMagick) for this: that can't be done. ImageMagick cannot process PDF input all by itself. It has to make use of Ghostscript anyway, so without a local Ghostscript installation it won't work. (You will not necessarily *see* Ghostscript at work while you feed PDF input to ImageMagick, unless you add a `-verbose` to its command line, because ImageMagick's delegation of the job to Ghostscript happens behind your back...)

Your question has two parts:

- *"Is there a way to "detect" extra wide pages, like the center spreads?"*
- *"Is there a way to crop the left and right parts from center spreads as two separate pages?"*

### Detect page sizes

You can use ImageMagick's `identify` to detect the page sizes of a PDF.

Just run the most simple command:

identify multipage.pdf

The output will be s.th. like

```
multipage.pdf[0] PDF 595x792 595x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 59.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.pdf[1] PDF 595x792 595x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 59.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.pdf[2] PDF 595x792 595x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 59.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.pdf[3] PDF 595x792 595x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 59.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

The output's page count is 0-based. So `[0]` indicates the first page, `[1]` the second page, etc.

To customize the output a bit better, you could do this:

```
identify -format '%f, page %s + 1: %W x %H\n' multipage.pdf
```

and get

```
multipage.pdf, page  0 + 1: 595 x 792
multipage.pdf, page  1 + 1: 595 x 792
multipage.pdf, page  2 + 1: 595 x 792
multipage.pdf, page  3 + 1: 595 x 792
```

For a double-spread page the respective output should be `1190 x 792` or similar.

**However, be warned:** to use ImageMagick for querying the page sizes of PDF files is veeeery slow. Therefor, better use a different tool for this sub-task: `pdfinfo`. This will be faster by several orders of magnitude:

```
pdfinfo -f 1 -l 1000 -box multipage.pdf
```

will output

```
Pages:          4
Page    1 size: 595 x 792 pts
Page    1 rot:  0
Page    2 size: 595 x 792 pts
Page    2 rot:  0
Page    3 size: 595 x 792 pts
Page    3 rot:  0
Page    4 size: 595 x 792 pts
Page    4 rot:  0
```

If you need additional info about the pages' ArtBox, TrimBox, BleedBox and CropBox values, just add `-box` to the commandline.

As I said: `pdfinfo` is significantly faster in identifying page sizes for PDFs than ImageMagick is. **Use the right tool for the job.**

### Crop left and right parts of a page

Now that you have identified the large double-spread page, you could use one of the following methods (based on Ghostscript) to split down the pages in the middle:

- [**How to crop a section of a PDF file to PNG using Ghostscript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12485020/359307)
- [**Split one PDF page into two**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521648/359307)
- [**Convert PDF 2 sides per page to 1 side per page**](https://superuser.com/a/189109/40894)
- [**How can I split a PDF's pages down the middle?**](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894)

Adapting the method described in above links will result in 2 PDF pages that still contain all their original vector and font info.

Alternatively, you can use ImageMagick. Assuming your 'double-spread' page is  of dimension 1190x842 pt, based on A4 (595x842 pt), and assuming it is page 16 (which translates to `[15]` for ImageMagick) inside an original PDF, your `convert` commands could be s.th. like:

```
convert  multipage.pdf[15]  -crop 595x842+0+0    page16-left.png
convert  multipage.pdf[15]  -crop 595x842+595+0  page16-right.png
```

The result gives you two raster images.