# GhostScript use bbox to crop Postscript file

Tags: command-line, runtime, crop, ghostscript, postscript

What I am trying to accomplish is to crop my PostScript file called example.ps using the output described in bbox. I am doing this in a batch process where the bbox might be different for certain files. I have looked at pdfcrop and seen that it uses a similar approach. Here is the command I am using to crop right now.

```
gs -o cropped.pdf \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=160 \
   -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=840 \
   -dFIXEDMEDIA \
   -c "0 0 translate 0 0 160 840 rectclip" \
   -f  example.ps
```

The issue with this command is that I have to specify what width and height to use. What I want to happen is to some how call bbox first and then call this statement either through code or by using some command line redirection.

Comment: it is straightforward to parse the input file, read the BB line and cook up the  appropriate gs command. The specifics will depend on what language you'd like to use.

Comment: The bbox line in the postscipt is not correct so I need to use the bbox command to find the correct bbox. Then create the gs command based on the output of bbox.

Comment: This is the windows cmd.exe shell? I could probably help with bash and awk, but I don't know windows that well at the moment.

Comment: well then you run gs twice, first with -sDEVICE=bbox, parse the output and again with the pdf device.  A more satisfying alternative would be to dive into the pdf device driver and give it an option to do what you want...

Comment: I tried redirecting the output of the gs command by including ">> out.txt" but i cant seem to capture the bbox output since the command invokes a shell.

Comment: @user1864948: see my answer about your problem to capture the `bbox` info in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be aware that not every single page from a multi-page PostScript file will show the exact same "bounding box" values (in fact, this is rather rare). So you probably want to find out the *common denominator* across all possible bounding boxes (which would include them all).

Second, what you see in the console window when you run `gs -sDEVICE=bbox` is a mix of *stdin* and *stdout* output channels. However, the info you're after is going to *stderr*. If you redirect the command output to a file, you're capturing *stdout*, not *stderr*! To suppress some of the version and debugging info going to *stderr* add `-q` to the commandline.

So in order to get a 'clean* output of the bounding boxes for all pages, you have to re-direct the *stderr* channel first, which you then capture in file *info.txt*.  So run a command like this (or similar):

```
gs              \
  -dBATCH       \
  -dNOPAUSE     \
  -q            \
  -sDEVICE=bbox \
   example.ps   \
2>&1            \
| tee info.txt
```

or even this, should you not need the info about the `HiResBoundingBox`:

```
gs              \
  -dBATCH       \
  -dNOPAUSE     \
  -q            \
  -sDEVICE=bbox \
   example.ps   \
2>&1            \
| grep ^%%Bound \
| tee info.txt
```

Also, BTW, note that can determine the bounding boxes of PostScript as well as PDF input files.

This should give you output like the following, where each line represents a page of the input file, starting with page 1 on the first line:

```
 %%BoundingBox: 36 18 553 802
 %%BoundingBox: 37 18 553 804
 %%BoundingBox: 36 18 553 802
 %%BoundingBox: 37 668 552 803
 %%BoundingBox: 40 68 532 757
```

**Lastly,** you might want to read up in the following answers for some background info about Ghostscript's `bbox` device. You'll also find some alternative PostScript code for the cropping job there:

- [**PDF - Remove White Margins**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418720/359307)
- [**How to crop a section of a PDF file to PNG using Ghostscript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12485020/359307)

Comment: I am using windows so I cant use the grep and tee command to redirect the stderr

Comment: @user1864948: On Windows, instead of grep you can use `findstr "%%Bound"`. Instead of `tee` you can use normal redirection: `1> info.txt`.